# How to design scale line like design in flutter

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, line, scale, product-quantity

I want to design below like scale line scrolling  design in flutter as pageview. it is used for select product quantity. is there any way to achieve this .

This is my figma design

[image]

I want to design below like scale line scrolling  design in flutter as pageview. it is used for select product quantity. is there any way to achieve this.  Thanks for advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use the [`ruler_scale_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/ruler_scale_picker) package.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:ruler_scale_picker/ruler_scale_picker.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(DefaultPage());
}

class DefaultPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DefaultPage({super.key, this.title});

  final String? title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title ?? 'Default'),
          scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
        ),
        body: const SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Expanded(child: NumericRulerScalePicker()),
              Expanded(
                child: NumericRulerScalePicker(
                  options: RulerScalePickerOptions(orientation: Axis.vertical),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```